# Localized frontend value for getCustomAttribute() (select or multiselect attributes)

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento-2.0, service-contract

Given a `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product` and `string $attributeCode` of an arbitrary attribute, I can access the attribute value, using:

```
$product->getCustomAttribute($attributeCode)->getValue();
```

This is the Service Contract variant of `$product->getData($attributeCode)`

Now I'm looking for an equivalent to `$product->getAttributeText($attributeCode)` because the attribute *might* be a "select" or "multiselect" type.

Is it possible, using only Service Contracts? If I load the attribute, using `Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeRepositoryInterface`, I could use `$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue()`, but this is again using implementation details that are not part of the Service Contract API.

Comment: Mate I'm afraid you're going to face a lot of walls trying to go the Service Contracts way for everything you want to achieve. But I'm with you, we should do some PR

Comment: True, but I'm going to continue to ask these questions when I'm hitting walls, and if it's just to highlight, where the API is incomplete, especially when it's about the catalog.

Comment: Totally agree with you